# Smoothdivscroll: (re)position scrollablearea div on click

Tags: jquery, html

I´m using smoothdivscroll to scroll on just one wide image in a smaller div container. I ve also added a thumbnail list and jquery functions to replace the large image when clicking on a thumbnail.

After clicking on a thumbnail the "scrollablearea" container does unfortunately not jump back to 0,0. until the next hover on a scrolling Hotspot.

You can try it here :

http://instinct-pictures.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=26&Itemid=139

scroll the first image to the left and click on the 2. thumbnail. The 2. Image stores the position of the old 1st image until the next hover.

I tried to position the "scrollablearea" manually with query but it did not work. Does anybody has a clue how to achieve this? Since I am using just one image I can not use the moveToElement function.

Find below my thumbnail click function:

```js
$('.thumbnail').live("click", function() {

    $('#main_Image').hide();

    var i = $('<img />').attr('src',this.href).load(function() {
        $('#main_Image').attr('src', i.attr('src'));
        $(".scrollableArea").css("width", $('#main_Image').width());
    $(".scrollableArea").css("left", 0);


        $('#main_Image').fadeIn();

    });
    return false; 
});
```